# Any Way to Populate Windows Explorer?

Tags: vba, vb6, webbrowser-control, explorer

Have generated a listing of files from multiple drives & folders in VB.  Would like to make them available for manipulating in windows explorer, as though they had been generated by a windows explorer search.
The explorer command-line options are quite limited.  Although files in an explorer folder can be selected programatically, I cannot find a way to add / preload files, particularly across drive/folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary folder (using Windows API) through VB. In that folder, you can create Symbolic Links to each of your files (whose paths and names you seem to have in VB program already). The following API (needs to be changed to VB-friendly style) can be used, or you could call Mklink command repeatedly. Caveat is: deleting or moving symlinks won't impact underlying files or folders. You might have to read up on Symlinks in Windows to determine if they meet your needs.

BOOLEAN WINAPI CreateSymbolicLink(
  *In* LPTSTR lpSymlinkFileName,
  *In* LPTSTR lpTargetFileName,
  *In* DWORD  dwFlags
);

Comment: Thanks MikeC... will take a look at Symlinks, but am looking for a direct method to force a fully manipulable filtered Explorer search-like result